# JavaScript have a variable in a variable name

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have a variable `varName`, which has the contents of "myvar". I want to create a variable that has the name of `variable` and the contents of `varName`, so the name would be `variablemyVar`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Love the fact Googling the exact title brought up the duplicate above. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
window["variable" + varName] = 42;
console.log(variablemyvar); // 42
```

This will make the variable global. Instead of `window`, you can use any scope (object), i.e.

```
var myObject = {
    someOtherVariable: 1337
};

myObject["variable" + varName] = 42;
console.log(myObject.variablemyvar); // 42
```

However, you should avoid doing this altogether whenever possible. The reason for this is that code like this breaks easy – say you want to rename the variable later on. Most likely you will overlook this, even the IDEs will. Another reason is that code minifiers will fail to minify this, if you set them to be "aggressive", it will even break the code during minification.

Lastly, especially using the first example with `window`, global variables are considered bad practice and should always be avoided, no matter how you declare them.

Comment: Also, you may want to explain _why_ it's advisable not to do this, rather than just stating it as a fact.

Comment: I added a few reasons. If you have more, feel free to edit them in :)